# Contact/User lookup gives error in on screen Flows

Tags: flow-screen-component

So the deal is that I'm trying to create a new record in a custom object (IT Order) used for internal orders. I would like to create a nice looking on screen UI experience to the employees. But when I add the Contact lookup, I only stumble upon the error message **"Select an option from the picklist or remove the search term."**
So no search results are found/displayed at all. 
[image]

If I change the Object API Name to the object I want to create the record to (IT Order), the error message changes to: **"You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access."**.
And I'm running the flow as an Administrator so I know I have the sufficient access.

This issue has not occurred earlier when the users used the New -button, and created the orders in the Salesforce standard new record detail view. The Contact field on the object itself has therefore worked flawlessly earlier.

I've checked on Youtube tutorials where they used lookup fields in on screen flows, and there it looks so simple, and I get the feeling I understand how it should work, but then when doing it myself I get stuck and frustrated.

Anyone got a guess or clue what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the actual api name of the custom object and not the label. Salesforce uses a naming structure that replaces spaces with underscores and ends with "__c". To find the api name of the object go to:

Setup --> Object Manager --> Your object (IT Order)

On the "Details" tab you will see an "API Name" field. In your example, the api name of the object would be "IT_order__c"

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work after some trial and error. The problem was that I hade a fundamental thought error here. I were trying to do work, that the flow/object itself was performing. ‍♂️